# How to get YouTube video Id by the video name?

Tags: android, android-studio, youtube-api, httpurlconnection

I am developing an android app, and I am trying to display a YouTube video, using the video name (with `YouTubePlayer` and `YouTubeBaceActivity`).

I am able to display the video if I have the video Id, but I don't know how to display the video by using only the video name.

I have tried to use `HttoUrlConnaction` by enter:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=<MOVIE_NAME>&type=video&key=<APIKEY>`

but it doesn't work for some reason and returns `FileNotFoundException` even though it works when I type the URL in google...

So how can I get the video Id, or how can I get the video only with the video name?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You can find how to get the Video ID's or video list [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#try-it). They have all the Request information needed for your youtube API calls.

As for why you are getting your FileNotFoundException even when it works when you type in the URL in google, **Usually this problem occurs when the developer forgets to add their oAuthToken as part of their headers, or plain and simple -- The url is wrong** 

Using HttpURLConnection, here is an example of how you can set request headers using the .setRequestProperty() method.

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        String response = null;

        try{
            //Create connection
            String url = requestURL;
            URL u = new URL(url);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", youtubeAuthToken);

            //Get Response, etc ,etc}
```

Answer (score 0):

Am assuming that you are getting a JSON thrown back from an endpoint. If thats the case then you can simply point to this endpoint and parse the JSON to get the respective urls that you can eventually render on your view. (Refer to following example).

You can use the Volley library or Retrofit library to handle the HTTP requests.

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```
private static final String endpoint = "http://api.youtube.********/json/videos.json";

//*************************************
//** JSON Video Output from Endpoint
//*************************************
[{
    "name": "Rocky V",
            "url": {
                "small": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VA770wpLX-Q&feature=youtube_gdata_player",
                "medium": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VA770wpLX-Q&feature=youtube_gdata_player",
                "large": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VA770wpLX-Q&feature=youtube_gdata_player"
    },
    "timestamp": "February 1, 2012"
},
{
    "name": "Rambo",
        "url": {
            "small": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VA770wpLX-Q&feature=youtube_gdata_player",
            "medium": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VA770wpLX-Q&feature=youtube_gdata_player",
            "large": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VA770wpLX-Q&feature=youtube_gdata_player"
},
    "timestamp": "March 5, 2014"
}]

//*************************************
//** Parse JSON to Fetch Videos
//*************************************
private void fetchVideos() {

    JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(endpoint,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                    videos.clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Video video = new Video();
                            video.setName(object.getString("name"));

                            JSONObject url = object.getJSONObject("url");
                            video.setSmall(url.getString("small"));
                            video.setMedium(url.getString("medium"));
                            video.setLarge(url.getString("large"));
                            video.setTimestamp(object.getString("timestamp"));

                            videos.add(video);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }

                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            //pDialog.hide();
        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    Application.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------
```